# Refresh image in CDN immediately after upload to S3 with same file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using amazon Cloudfront CDN with S3 behind as the origin server to serve images like profile photos of users on my application. I store a user's profile photo with file name as *`<userId>.jpg`*. When the user changes his profile photo, how do I refresh the image in the CDN **immediately** ?

Since the filename is *`<userId>.jpg`* I cannot have a new name for the new image.

Comment: CDNs aren't meant to replace images immediately. That's standard behavior for a cache. You can work around it with a query string (suboptimal) or `cache-control` settings, but.. it's missing the point of a CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to store a count of how many times it has been changed and use something like `<userId>.jpg?v=2` on your site. You'd have to turn query strings on for the CloudFront distribution.

Without a filename change or query string change, you'd have to use a CloudFront invalidation, which will take up to about 15 minutes to take effect everywhere.

Comment: maintaining & using counter for file change events would be a bit troublesome for me.. no way to respond with the most latest version with some random large value in query string ?

Comment: Sure, you could use a random number there. You'd lose pretty much all benefits of a CDN if that number changed every pageview, though.

Comment: Thanks. Is query string appended url also a way to invalidate the cloudfront cache, I mean after once requesting url file with query string, will the subsequent requests to url without query string return fresh updated image ?

Comment: @user01 No. CloudFront treats them as two entirely separate items.

Answer (score 0):

Automating through AWS's own LAMBDA would be the best thing. I can't take credit for this script, only found it on Google.

https://gist.github.com/supinf/e66fd36f9228a8701706